# This part fell off my car

Tags: toyota, part-identification, 4runner

Any idea what it is or what it’s for? Are there safety concerns? It’s about the size of a watch / bracelet.

It’s from a 2006 Toyota 4Runner.

Thanks for any help!![image: ![mystery car part]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xxX1.jpg)

Comment: My guess would be it was helping support part of the exhaust.

Comment: What is the diameter? We need a size reference please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say for certain exactly where it came from, but that is a bracket which would be used to secure a pipe or secure something to a pipe. I can think of the following cases it's likely to be:

1. Secure the exhaust manifold or exhaust pipe. If the exhaust comes loose you could get the exhaust in your car which would be unpleasant and in extreme cases impair your driving
2. Attach a heat shield to an exhaust pipe to protect sensitive parts of the car from heat. A missing heat shield could damage your car, or start a fire (it has happened, that's why they put heat shields on in the first place)
3. Attach wiring to something circular (this less likely)

I recommend you get it fixed and not ignore it, replacing it now will keep things from getting worse, or you might discover something more urgent.

Comment: Glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

Also called a "hose clamp" ; I would look at all hoses , some may carry air . In addition to the exhaust system although it looks thin for an exhaust system component. Start looking at the lower radiator hose. I think there is a very good chance it is important.